# What does conjugation in the time-domain of a signal mean?

Tags: education, signal-processing

I've never been explicitly told what the conjugation of a signal in the time-domain means. I'm mainly asking because in my signals class, my professor stated that for a signal x(t) to be real: x(t) = x(t)*, and I don't understand why.

Comment: $z=z^*$, where $z^*$ is the complex conjugate of $z$, if and only if $z$ is real. This is because the imaginary part will be $0$, and only $0$ satisfies $0=-0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 
$$
z\equiv a+ib
$$
is a complex number ($a$ and $b$ are real numbers), its conjugate
is defined to be
$$
\overline{z}\equiv a-ib.
$$

Note that we can write a real number $x$ as
$$
x=x+i0.
$$
The conjugate of $x$ is equal to itself:
$$
\overline{x}=x-i0=x.
$$
Therefore, **if a number is real, it is equal to its conjugate**.

For the converse, if $z\equiv a+ib$ is equal to its conjugate,
$$
a+ib=a-ib
$$
which implies
$$
ib=-ib.
$$
If $b$ is anything other than zero, we arrive at a contradiction,
since $i\neq-i$. **Therefore, if a complex number is equal to its conjugate, it is real.**

All that remains to be done is to apply your result pointwise (i.e. for every possible time $t$), and you arrive at the result $x(t)=x(t)^*$ for all $t$ if and only if $x(t)$ is real for all $t$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see now. :)

Comment: Please accept if you are content with the answer. David H's answer below is also correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z$ be some fixed but arbitrary complex number with Cartesian representation $z=\Re{(z)}+i\,\Im{(z)}$ for some real pair $(\Re{(z)},\Im{(z)})\in\mathbb{R}^2$. The complex conjugate of $z$ is then,

$$z^*=\Re{(z)}-i\,\Im{(z)}.$$

Subtracting the conjugate of $z$ from $z$ itself then yields:

$$\begin{align}
z-z^*
&=(\Re{(z)}+i\,\Im{(z)})-(\Re{(z)}-i\,\Im{(z)})\\
&=2i\,\Im{(z)}.
\end{align}$$

Solving for the imaginary component of $z$, we have:

$$\Im{(z)}=\frac{z-z^*}{2i}.$$

Thus, if $z\neq z^*$, or equivalently if $z-z^*\neq 0$, then $\Im{(z)}\neq 0$. Contrapositively, if $\Im{(z)}=0$ then $z=z^*$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you!! Very helpful :)

Comment: @Charles: If you find David's post helpful, please up-vote it.

Comment: Oh, I wish I could, but I'm new to the site.

Comment: @Charles My pleasure. Welcome to the StackExchange. :)